# I can t access fields of map<string,string>

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, stl

I can figure it out why my compiler response like this when i try to access ->first and ->second fields of iterator. I used before a map structure but not with a string as key.

ERROR:  error C2675: unary '++' : 'std::string' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void display(map <string, string> v){
    map <string, string> ::iterator it = v.begin();
    map <string, string> ::iterator end = v.end();
    for (; it != end; ++it){
        cout << "Name:" << it->first << "---->";
        cout << "Adress:" << it->second << endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    map <string, string > v;
    string name;
    string adress;

    do
    {
        cout << "Name:";
        cin >> name;  // getline(cin, name);
        cout << "\nAdress:";
        cin >> adress; // getline(cin, adress);
        v.insert(name, adress);

    } while (name == "exit");

    display(v);
}
```

Can you tell me guys what am I writing wrong?

Comment: `insert` expects a pair. Try `v.emplace(name, address);` instead.

Comment: btw i guess you want `while (name != "exit")`

Comment: You are passing the `map` by *copy*.  Do you want to do this?  I recommend passing it by reference.

Comment: use a std::pair for map::insert like this - v.insert(std::pair<string,string>(name, adress));

Comment: pedantically, `v.insert( decltype(v)::value_type(name, address) );`